# Custom Spring Security filter chain returns 404

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm implementing a custom Spring Security filter in a Grails application that I want to only be applied when the user submits the login form.

My Spring Security settings in the config file look like this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'package.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'package.Role'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['anonymousAuthenticationProvider', 'apiServiceProvider']

grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/css/**': 'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/home/**': 'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/images/**': 'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/js/**': 'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
]

grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true

grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [          
        '/j_spring_security_check': 'myFilter',
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS'
]
```

The filter class looks like this:

```
class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse)
    }

    @Override
    void destroy() {}
}
```

The above is wired up as a Spring bean in the resources.groovy file like so:

```
beans = {
    myFilter (MyFilter)
    ...
}
```

When I navigate to the login page and press 'Submit' on the form, the browser requests the path /j_spring_security_check within the application, the filter gets run (as determined by a debugger breakpoint), but a 404 error is returned to the browser.

Without the filter in the configuration, i.e. if 
`'/j_spring_security_check': 'myFilter',`
is commented out, the application works fine.

I've tried various solutions described in other SO questions to no avail.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was pretty obvious now I've fixed it... I needed to include all of the other standard Spring filters in the map entry for the j_spring_security_check URL. The filter map in the configuration then becomes:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/j_spring_security_check': 'myFilter,securityContextPersistenceFilter,logoutFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,anonymousAuthenticationFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS'
]
```